# Canvas in Android Browser - bad animation

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, kineticjs

I have a problem with animation in KineticJS on Android browsers. Here is my code:

http://dev.bordeux.net/canvas/

QR Code Link:

[image: QRCode link]

So on Chrome, Opera, Firefox, IE everything is ok, but on Android 4.3 (i don't now how it is in older versions) looks like this:

[image: Proble]

What is wrong with my code? How can i optimize  my html5 application?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's the same canvas bug, as described here: https://medium.com/p/ffcb939af758

I don't known how KineticJS works, but for HTML5 canvas, following trick works for me:

```
canvas.width = canvas.width;
```